# University Problem about interpolation Implied volatility BS Model (volatility smile)

Tags: options, black-scholes, implied-volatility, delta, volatility-smile

Good morning,
this is my first question on this forum, I'm writing from Milan (Italy) and I have a question about a University Problem.
The problem is about entering in a Long Range Forward (buy a call option and sell a put option). Now, the goal is to calculate the Strike of the option and get the volatility smile with this data:

Notional = 100.000,00
S(0) = 100,00
Delta Call = 20%
Call Volatility = 10%
Put Volatility = 12%

I tried to solve the problem and I get that in the black model I have:

Delta Put = 1 - Delta Call = 0,8 (80%)

also in the Black Model it is true -> Delta Call = 0,2 = N(d1) so I caculated d1 = -0,8405

at this point I don't know how I can solve it
ca you help me? I've the final test on 1st December
is the problem impossible to solve because of missing data?

Thank you

Comment: Just to clarify: The put and call have different but unknown strikes and you want to calculate the strike of each of the two options, given their implied volatility, value of the underlying and delta under a 76 Black model? [btw: good luck with your exam!]

Comment: yes my problem's that and I've to provide the volatility smile plot

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Ivan. Are you sure that the value of the spot is given, not the futures price (i.e, no information about interest rates or dividends)? Do you know the maturity of these options?

Comment: As you say, $\Delta_c=N(d_1)$, where $d_1=\frac{\ln(F/K)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$. Thus, given $d_1$ (which you calculated correctly), we can solve easily for the strike price: $K=F\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2T-d_1\sigma\sqrt{T}\right)$. However, we do need to know the maturity of the option ($T$) and the futures price ($F$).

Comment: Yes my problem is that I haven't maturity and interest rate, is it possible to solve it without this information? however is the strike price for Put option like K with -(-d1) so +d1?

Comment: Are you sure you're interested in the Black model (for futures) or are you meant to use the Black-Scholes model (for standard vanilla options)? I think you'll need the time to maturity in either case. Is there any other information available?

Comment: if I'm not wrong in B&S model ∆c = N(d1) * exp(-r*T) so in this case I can't calculate d1. Otherwise I tried with each model. I haven't other information, with the available data is it possible to get new information about Rate or Time to Maturity? is there any way?

Comment: If there are dividends, then $\Delta_c=N(d_1)e^{-qT}$ but if there are no dividends, then $\Delta_c=N(d_1)$. This applies to the Black-Scholes model. You seem to be switching between the Black (1976) model and the Black-Scholes (1973) model. You seem to be missing information on option strikes, maturities and interest rates. I can't see how you can infer all of this from the given option prices. Please Ivan, feek free to reach out if you have more information and I'll be happy to help you (: but as of now I don't think your question is quite answerable.

Comment: Thank you Kevin

Comment: I forgot: Good luck with your exam! :) If there's anything I can help you with during your exam preparation please let me know!

Comment: Thank you, I forget to tell you that I have another problem that I can't resolve can you help me? I posted a question

Comment: You mean the bond option question? Could dm63 answer your question? Also, please always feel free to reach out directly if you have questions about these topics! [see my profile] Good luck with your exam!